# How to keep duplicates in a pandas groupby max?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df`

```
        date  close
0 2006-01-02  143.2
1 2006-01-07  165.2
2 2008-09-19  198.0
3 2008-12-20  198.0
```

I want to groupby year and find the maximum close **such that duplicates are kept.**

So far what I have is

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.year).max()[["close"]]
           date  close
date                  
2006 2006-01-07  165.2
2008 2008-12-20  198.0
```

whereas what I want is the two `close` values in 2008 since they are identical

```
           date  close
date                  
2006 2006-01-07  165.2
2008 2008-09-19  198.0
2008 2008-12-20  198.0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Check solution with `groupby.transform`

Comment: ```df.groupby(df.date.dt.year).filter(lambda x: x.close.eq(x.close.max()).all())``` maybe? this will be slower than @jezrael suggestion of transform

Comment: Use `df[df.groupby(df.date.dt.year)['close'].transform('max').eq(df["close"])]`